# [Solution]The spark context has stopped and the driver is restarting. Your notebook will be automatically reattached

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

If your notebook or diver program is getting killed with the below error

**Code**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
def main():
    spark_sess = SparkSession.builder.appName('app_name').config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension").config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog").getOrCreate()
    print("hello")
    spark_sess.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error:

```
The spark context has stopped and the driver is restarting. Your notebook will be automatically reattached
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you are doing any of it.

1. spark_context.stop()
2. Memory of cluster

We should not stop spark context when we run anything in databricks.

Comment: Is there a way to check the cause in the spark or databricks logs?

Answer (score 0):

driver is not having enough memory to handle your data in driver side .